# Automatically adding images directly from python code (preferably using VSCode)

Tags: graphics, automation, python

Imagine I have some python code that generates an image.

e.g.

```python
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    # Data for plotting
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, s)
    
    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
           title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
    ax.grid()
    
    fig.savefig("test.png")
    plt.show()
```

And I want to add the image generated by this code to my LaTeX document automatically, so that if I change the code the image will change when I compile the document again.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can do with the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en) package: make changes to your code in the document and then rebuild it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#### Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)',ylabel='voltage (mV)',title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()
fig.savefig("test.png")
\end{sagesilent}
Sagetex let's you put Python code into your \LaTeX \,document.
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5in,height=4in]{test.png}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output is shown below:
[image]

Since `sagetex` is not part of a LaTeX distribution the easiest way to try it is with a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. In about 5-10 minutes you'll be up and running. Just copy/paste the code into a new LaTeX document.